# Application not running in iOS 5

Tags: memory-management, ios5

my application was running successfully in iOS 3.2 but when I installed iOS 5 on my iPad it crashes. I had searched in many places however I could find the solution. I think error is in the last function having name "connectionDidFinishLoading". Following is the crash report of my app :

```
Incident Identifier: 4BE5CDC2-605B-4536-8136-8252C1CD60D6
CrashReporter Key:   0ed3b9166caa3e4c6257ee94d1c3fc3bcded36f8
Hardware Model:      iPad1,1
Process:         OrderWork [2106]
Path:            /var/mobile/Applications/13BBBCAE-2938-4459-8628-FCF7E3EB0E4C/OrderWork.app/OrderWork
Identifier:      OrderWork
Version:         ??? (???)
Code Type:       ARM (Native)
Parent Process:  launchd [1]

Date/Time:       2011-11-02 12:03:14.450 +0530
OS Version:      iPhone OS 5.0 (9A334)
Report Version:  104

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0xf0000008
Crashed Thread:  0

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x308b1fbc 0x308ae000 + 16316
1   Foundation                      0x33046e4e 0x32f9d000 + 695886
2   OrderWork                       0x00004b32 -[supplyworks connectionDidFinishLoading:] (supplyworks.m:580)
3   Foundation                      0x33063c32 0x32f9d000 + 814130
4   Foundation                      0x32fbb6e2 0x32f9d000 + 124642
5   Foundation                      0x32fbb6ac 0x32f9d000 + 124588
6   Foundation                      0x32fbb5ce 0x32f9d000 + 124366
7   CFNetwork                       0x3204a8fa 0x3203b000 + 63738
8   CFNetwork                       0x3203f59a 0x3203b000 + 17818
9   CFNetwork                       0x3203f68e 0x3203b000 + 18062
10  CFNetwork                       0x3203f298 0x3203b000 + 17048
11  CFNetwork                       0x3203f1ce 0x3203b000 + 16846
12  CoreFoundation                  0x3574eafc 0x356c1000 + 580348
13  CoreFoundation                  0x3574e2c8 0x356c1000 + 578248
14  CoreFoundation                  0x3574d06e 0x356c1000 + 573550
15  CoreFoundation                  0x356d04d6 0x356c1000 + 62678
16  CoreFoundation                  0x356d039e 0x356c1000 + 62366
17  GraphicsServices                0x37663fe6 0x37660000 + 16358
18  UIKit                           0x3186d73c 0x3183c000 + 202556
19  OrderWork                       0x0000263e main (main.m:14)
20  OrderWork                       0x00002608 start + 32

Thread 1 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x35ed83b4 0x35ed7000 + 5044
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x3312be78 0x3311f000 + 52856
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x3312bb96 0x3311f000 + 52118

Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x35ee8cd4 0x35ed7000 + 72916
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x35efb30a 0x35ef1000 + 41738
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x35efb09c 0x35ef1000 + 41116

Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x35ee8cd4 0x35ed7000 + 72916
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x35efb30a 0x35ef1000 + 41738
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x35efb09c 0x35ef1000 + 41116

Thread 4 name:  WebThread
Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x35ed8010 0x35ed7000 + 4112
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x35ed8206 0x35ed7000 + 4614
2   CoreFoundation                  0x3574e41c 0x356c1000 + 578588
3   CoreFoundation                  0x3574d154 0x356c1000 + 573780
4   CoreFoundation                  0x356d04d6 0x356c1000 + 62678
5   CoreFoundation                  0x356d039e 0x356c1000 + 62366
6   WebCore                         0x32828128 0x32780000 + 688424
7   libsystem_c.dylib               0x35f00c16 0x35ef1000 + 64534
8   libsystem_c.dylib               0x35f00ad0 0x35ef1000 + 64208

Thread 5:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x35ee8cd4 0x35ed7000 + 72916
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x35efb30a 0x35ef1000 + 41738
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x35efb09c 0x35ef1000 + 41116

Thread 6 name:  com.apple.NSURLConnectionLoader
Thread 6:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x35ed8010 0x35ed7000 + 4112
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x35ed8206 0x35ed7000 + 4614
2   CoreFoundation                  0x3574e41c 0x356c1000 + 578588
3   CoreFoundation                  0x3574d154 0x356c1000 + 573780
4   CoreFoundation                  0x356d04d6 0x356c1000 + 62678
5   CoreFoundation                  0x356d039e 0x356c1000 + 62366
6   Foundation                      0x32fadbc2 0x32f9d000 + 68546
7   Foundation                      0x32fada8a 0x32f9d000 + 68234
8   Foundation                      0x3304159a 0x32f9d000 + 673178
9   libsystem_c.dylib               0x35f00c16 0x35ef1000 + 64534
10  libsystem_c.dylib               0x35f00ad0 0x35ef1000 + 64208

Thread 7:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x35ee8cd4 0x35ed7000 + 72916
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x35efb30a 0x35ef1000 + 41738
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x35efb09c 0x35ef1000 + 41116

Thread 8:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x35ee8cd4 0x35ed7000 + 72916
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x35efb30a 0x35ef1000 + 41738
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x35efb09c 0x35ef1000 + 41116

Thread 9 name:  com.apple.CFSocket.private
Thread 9:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x35ee80a0 0x35ed7000 + 69792
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x35ef442a 0x35ef1000 + 13354
2   CoreFoundation                  0x356cb56a 0x356c1000 + 42346
3   CoreFoundation                  0x3575312a 0x356c1000 + 598314
4   libsystem_c.dylib               0x35f00c16 0x35ef1000 + 64534
5   libsystem_c.dylib               0x35f00ad0 0x35ef1000 + 64208

Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State:
    r0: 0x001caab0    r1: 0x36ae6830      r2: 0x001ea390      r3: 0x00000000
    r4: 0xf0000000    r5: 0x001e7690      r6: 0x3ed37a38      r7: 0x2fdfea4c
    r8: 0x001caab0    r9: 0x0dab9a0c     r10: 0x3ed22378     r11: 0x3ed37a18
    ip: 0x3ecfd6f0    sp: 0x2fdfea20      lr: 0x33046e55      pc: 0x308b1fbc
  cpsr: 0x000f0030

Binary Images:
    0x1000 -    0x2cfff +OrderWork armv7  <f2cd5118d1d9fbdcba3b8cef5481ad5f> /var/mobile/Applications/13BBBCAE-2938-4459-8628-FCF7E3EB0E4C/OrderWork.app/OrderWork
0x2fefd000 - 0x2ff1efff  dyld armv7  <be7c0b491a943054ad12eb5060f1da06> /usr/lib/dyld
0x307ca000 - 0x3081bfff  libstdc++.6.dylib armv7  <dc2061145c1a3307829d4f3bfc547c1a> /usr/lib/libstdc++.6.dylib
0x308ae000 - 0x30974fff  libobjc.A.dylib armv7  <d503b4ad04313023bbe76ededd30ed70> /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib
0x30986000 - 0x309c9fff  libcommonCrypto.dylib armv7  <be9a231cfe6e3ae387abb444a098bce9> /usr/lib/system/libcommonCrypto.dylib
0x30ad7000 - 0x30adefff  AssetsLibraryServices armv7  <f6d1bb9e4b60392f834d4e0ee35105cc> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AssetsLibraryServices.framework/AssetsLibraryServices
0x30aec000 - 0x30afbfff  OpenGLES armv7  <6d1afb451f50310895ec59864739e781> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/OpenGLES
0x30c3f000 - 0x30d19fff  vImage armv7  <42a5e58ff1b9350cad90de36bd3ceb09> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vImage.framework/vImage
0x30e21000 - 0x30e61fff  libGLImage.dylib armv7  <9440420d838a382caa175399d74a5044> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libGLImage.dylib
0x30e70000 - 0x30eb9fff  AddressBook armv7  <9ac3368232663b5786382e33c3773678> /System/Library/Frameworks/AddressBook.framework/AddressBook
0x30ed9000 - 0x30f0efff  SystemConfiguration armv7  <68dbad71a3cc32e5941ad70820f88caa> /System/Library/Frameworks/SystemConfiguration.framework/SystemConfiguration
0x30f15000 - 0x30f15fff  libunwind.dylib armv7  <d21222aad8c93d6c9580f9bf47071946> /usr/lib/system/libunwind.dylib
0x31061000 - 0x31067fff  liblockdown.dylib armv7  <4e3671438f71326bbc507cb197a31322> /usr/lib/liblockdown.dylib
0x3106a000 - 0x3106dfff  CaptiveNetwork armv7  <c3a5b1659eb0302eb205498ffacb09f1> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CaptiveNetwork.framework/CaptiveNetwork
0x3109c000 - 0x310a0fff  libcache.dylib armv7  <607095842baf3c41be3127ed773582ea> /usr/lib/system/libcache.dylib
0x310b2000 - 0x310d1fff  libSystem.B.dylib armv7  <17803796ac1d31bdab85e651a74d5e0d> /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
0x31102000 - 0x3115dfff  StoreServices armv7  <01e6b5e7449d39b8bc11e39fc217e645> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/StoreServices.framework/StoreServices
0x311f7000 - 0x3120dfff  DictionaryServices armv7  <ff80b6648c24360583e5e624efda4815> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DictionaryServices.framework/DictionaryServices
0x3120e000 - 0x3120efff  vecLib armv7  <106ef8294b0d3c2d89e9230527846227> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/vecLib
0x3120f000 - 0x31253fff  MobileCoreServices armv7  <e05a113469ed345f98f306965abb30dc> /System/Library/Frameworks/MobileCoreServices.framework/MobileCoreServices
0x31255000 - 0x31256fff  libremovefile.dylib armv7  <77460820431837d68f19c81d53b6ca83> /usr/lib/system/libremovefile.dylib
0x31345000 - 0x31371fff  libtidy.A.dylib armv7  <f0eca72c10c537fa89b17fd97e003faf> /usr/lib/libtidy.A.dylib
0x3137a000 - 0x31386fff  libCRFSuite.dylib armv7  <ea460e3f1ac338a9885d5752864dbffb> /usr/lib/libCRFSuite.dylib
0x31387000 - 0x3138bfff  FTClientServices armv7  <0f8bfadbf83a35c39f4ac39045ca569d> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FTClientServices.framework/FTClientServices
0x31442000 - 0x31587fff  CoreGraphics armv7  <649b7b4a430a340b8c2b85c6fb4e1369> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/CoreGraphics
0x31649000 - 0x3164afff  libdyld.dylib armv7  <f1963e7ef64e39a58ec1e39ed7c74849> /usr/lib/system/libdyld.dylib
0x3164f000 - 0x316f9fff  libBLAS.dylib armv7  <9aabff01422f3cb8960f93d11d2b6de1> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libBLAS.dylib
0x3176e000 - 0x31784fff  EAP8021X armv7  <3f7bd850face343495b2c542ef63d44d> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/EAP8021X.framework/EAP8021X
0x317a6000 - 0x317acfff  MobileIcons armv7  <2f4c13053206306996726629b0b7eb01> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileIcons.framework/MobileIcons
0x3183c000 - 0x31cd5fff  UIKit armv7  <87348d5d0d043aa095840765b6d73999> /System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/UIKit
0x31cd6000 - 0x31cdcfff  libnotify.dylib armv7  <19d7596821403d998017f03678d40514> /usr/lib/system/libnotify.dylib
0x31d8e000 - 0x31dc9fff  libCGFreetype.A.dylib armv7  <1f70c1e94e333f0bb0866143b2abb0a7> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Resources/libCGFreetype.A.dylib
0x31dce000 - 0x31dcefff  liblangid.dylib armv7  <342170169bf232a0888912f5ef97112d> /usr/lib/liblangid.dylib
0x31e3c000 - 0x31e61fff  OpenCL armv7  <051a834ba5583f47876f0c8b9a1e3dda> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/OpenCL.framework/OpenCL
0x31e62000 - 0x31e69fff  libc++abi.dylib armv7  <f769ce305c3033ee90e8c2ecc4846619> /usr/lib/libc++abi.dylib
0x31e83000 - 0x31f29fff  AddressBookUI armv7  <90b13f7f5d6c38f68efba5944faa2ad4> /System/Library/Frameworks/AddressBookUI.framework/AddressBookUI
0x31f2a000 - 0x31f4dfff  Bom armv7  <0e6087f75a81345ea81751197ccb712c> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Bom.framework/Bom
0x32000000 - 0x32015fff  libresolv.9.dylib armv7  <2e35ec83cc823bbebf107dc4867e61d7> /usr/lib/libresolv.9.dylib
0x3203b000 - 0x32112fff  CFNetwork armv7  <794a80e086d23041bfdec139b01e80a2> /System/Library/Frameworks/CFNetwork.framework/CFNetwork
0x32123000 - 0x32134fff  libxpc.dylib armv7  <637167f4fa5c3cee99418295843e1580> /usr/lib/system/libxpc.dylib
0x32191000 - 0x32195fff  libAccessibility.dylib armv7  <ee734c0e964934a887a66d170270b114> /usr/lib/libAccessibility.dylib
0x32196000 - 0x321a0fff  libbz2.1.0.dylib armv7  <28583efb9f1b38e7ae83c667b07dbd08> /usr/lib/libbz2.1.0.dylib
0x3220e000 - 0x3220ffff  libsystem_blocks.dylib armv7  <4bb9797771d037879bec814fe750d86d> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_blocks.dylib
0x32338000 - 0x32371fff  VideoToolbox armv7  <49f9f09f23f7396b94a29bb1280759fe> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/VideoToolbox.framework/VideoToolbox
0x32372000 - 0x3237efff  CoreVideo armv7  <474c89eb09fe3464851a20d76052341b> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreVideo.framework/CoreVideo
0x3237f000 - 0x32384fff  libsystem_dnssd.dylib armv7  <11ce894432a73b9485cce6f5b1ea6488> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_dnssd.dylib
0x32385000 - 0x3238bfff  MobileKeyBag armv7  <18472eec0dfa3aa993f4ae7f34ec5c52> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileKeyBag.framework/MobileKeyBag
0x3239c000 - 0x323f2fff  GMM armv7  <a88c7f8dc6d7322c904325ffa551bf1d> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GMM.framework/GMM
0x32462000 - 0x32466fff  IOMobileFramebuffer armv7  <c2e6bd6dafde3097b47bc255a8c871ef> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IOMobileFramebuffer.framework/IOMobileFramebuffer
0x32469000 - 0x3246cfff  libcompiler_rt.dylib armv7  <414332f9a55238bab2cbec323e0fc8da> /usr/lib/system/libcompiler_rt.dylib
0x3247f000 - 0x3249ffff  libxslt.1.dylib armv7  <f37418b7e89137bba433677d61cd779d> /usr/lib/libxslt.1.dylib
0x324aa000 - 0x324fbfff  CoreText armv7  <23150093d39b393e9bc5f8230176df47> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreText.framework/CoreText
0x324fc000 - 0x32506fff  libvMisc.dylib armv7  <b93ee3136d1c3d44b1e513a56bb0f86c> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libvMisc.dylib
0x32566000 - 0x32654fff  libiconv.2.dylib armv7  <0f52661fd7af3a448b95f8d93d20f3f7> /usr/lib/libiconv.2.dylib
0x32679000 - 0x32688fff  SpringBoardServices armv7  <083fb830455f3cd0869bf54bfd91108c> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SpringBoardServices.framework/SpringBoardServices
0x3268f000 - 0x3277ffff  QuartzCore armv7  <c77ceeffd75e3bcc9df3bbe91e2dac98> /System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/QuartzCore
0x32780000 - 0x32f37fff  WebCore armv7  <5a60e1e3f68331e5b426dd4dfeb3def8> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebCore.framework/WebCore
0x32f5c000 - 0x32f61fff  libcopyfile.dylib armv7  <49003f67c59730c9ac9c499517a3bb8b> /usr/lib/system/libcopyfile.dylib
0x32f8b000 - 0x32f9cfff  DataAccessExpress armv7  <2306f236fe113baba3934f1884d36a47> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataAccessExpress.framework/DataAccessExpress
0x32f9d000 - 0x3311bfff  Foundation armv7  <c1afe35de1f63b0db5b7ced0dec7163f> /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Foundation
0x3311f000 - 0x33135fff  libdispatch.dylib armv7  <86ed1499ae1e3f5ba389e657f6a23ced> /usr/lib/system/libdispatch.dylib
0x3316e000 - 0x3334bfff  AudioToolbox armv7  <59dd50551a893636b94bf4505a62ef97> /System/Library/Frameworks/AudioToolbox.framework/AudioToolbox
0x3334c000 - 0x33388fff  AppSupport armv7  <202262953e2d343cbf489fe1e308dba4> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AppSupport.framework/AppSupport
0x33391000 - 0x33395fff  AggregateDictionary armv7  <cfd957904957310381369729bfd9b2b0> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AggregateDictionary.framework/AggregateDictionary
0x33396000 - 0x33397fff  CoreSurface armv7  <fcb6a869daef3a3abc4300c28b218e9f> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreSurface.framework/CoreSurface
0x334c4000 - 0x33534fff  CoreImage armv7  <b1d0678497f43769840f173c0f9dce20> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreImage.framework/CoreImage
0x33535000 - 0x33539fff  libGFXShared.dylib armv7  <0a36fb9d60a43479943bafb2f81313b1> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libGFXShared.dylib
0x335a8000 - 0x335aafff  libCoreVMClient.dylib armv7  <6ddb7cf8a93830628787a5b83eea0f1d> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libCoreVMClient.dylib
0x342d2000 - 0x34816fff  FaceCoreLight armv7  <cc2edb3645d2390dbca5471d35f1bf6e> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FaceCoreLight.framework/FaceCoreLight
0x34868000 - 0x348adfff  GeoServices armv7  <6c9eb6372f723a57852cfc9ed7b78e31> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GeoServices.framework/GeoServices
0x348da000 - 0x348dbfff  libdnsinfo.dylib armv7  <1dadb6191d1835e5b078594218ce14f3> /usr/lib/system/libdnsinfo.dylib
0x3494f000 - 0x3495afff  AccountSettings armv7  <090bb6a4f97433089b5cabc6a40c619a> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AccountSettings.framework/AccountSettings
0x34a6d000 - 0x34ab7fff  CoreTelephony armv7  <7cb3680db3bb36a0b59b6d8e8cecf374> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreTelephony.framework/CoreTelephony
0x34aea000 - 0x34b07fff  libsystem_info.dylib armv7  <8e5dd82833293382a08f11517e9dcb9b> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_info.dylib
0x34b76000 - 0x34b7dfff  ProtocolBuffer armv7  <00599097fff03d02896974966dee6dda> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ProtocolBuffer.framework/ProtocolBuffer
0x34c26000 - 0x34c62fff  IMFoundation armv7  <782ea3e246093c56a7bc04f60c8ca1b3> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IMCore.framework/Frameworks/IMFoundation.framework/IMFoundation
0x34c89000 - 0x34c8afff  libsystem_sandbox.dylib armv7  <b8612b4ce18535aaa94f4b75c730e090> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_sandbox.dylib
0x34cff000 - 0x34e23fff  JavaScriptCore armv7  <322e347adc08308ca55fc7de9598248c> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/JavaScriptCore.framework/JavaScriptCore
0x35046000 - 0x35053fff  libbsm.0.dylib armv7  <a6414b0a5fd53df58c4f0b2f8878f81f> /usr/lib/libbsm.0.dylib
0x351f4000 - 0x35351fff  libmecabra.dylib armv7  <170c82a3c716372abe7ae0aae96d4805> /usr/lib/libmecabra.dylib
0x35356000 - 0x3536cfff  libmis.dylib armv7  <fd046316dedc34dd81a6601ea3b1e8a6> /usr/lib/libmis.dylib
0x3536d000 - 0x353effff  MapKit armv7  <0aa2be229fc13ef091c124f5bdaff848> /System/Library/Frameworks/MapKit.framework/MapKit
0x35412000 - 0x3555bfff  libicucore.A.dylib armv7  <1bc960f75d633190a09b093209a9f0c5> /usr/lib/libicucore.A.dylib
0x3555c000 - 0x3555efff  MobileInstallation armv7  <4c0648df13af341e88ddca80be687794> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileInstallation.framework/MobileInstallation
0x3561a000 - 0x3567dfff  IMCore armv7  <8dbf71fc51af3424ac33348db251ba0a> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IMCore.framework/IMCore
0x356c1000 - 0x357d8fff  CoreFoundation armv7  <a2dbc131fdc0364e822339ca2926b6e8> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation
0x357e6000 - 0x3582ffff  libc++.1.dylib armv7  <ad15503487243836b7c296f3439ba0c1> /usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib
0x35830000 - 0x358a9fff  ProofReader armv7  <09d057676f6837cd9e7a735444b67e77> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ProofReader.framework/ProofReader
0x35ad3000 - 0x35b52fff  libsqlite3.dylib armv7  <cdd807e0d8523476b666a9dc63750bb7> /usr/lib/libsqlite3.dylib
0x35b53000 - 0x35b67fff  PersistentConnection armv7  <47b0ba3bcfd230a192119445de86cef1> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PersistentConnection.framework/PersistentConnection
0x35c20000 - 0x35c2cfff  libz.1.dylib armv7  <8e4095644cc33c97aa5f9f0620387f88> /usr/lib/libz.1.dylib
0x35ed7000 - 0x35eedfff  libsystem_kernel.dylib armv7  <ac287acb68d032118cd824a51011638d> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_kernel.dylib
0x35ef1000 - 0x35f7efff  libsystem_c.dylib armv7  <2eb267ac3b5e32b0a43a61ccb98e6dd1> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib
0x35f8f000 - 0x35f93fff  Marco armv7  <5a1a8ed254ec3fb899ae70121a9c69b9> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Marco.framework/Marco
0x35f97000 - 0x3612ffff  CoreData armv7  <75030d6f36f9394592dd35af610e8960> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreData.framework/CoreData
0x36133000 - 0x36137fff  IOSurface armv7  <0f003f50b18e3dbf87607d819e0ac6b9> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IOSurface.framework/IOSurface
0x36314000 - 0x3635efff  libvDSP.dylib armv7  <d8489a4ce77933abac52394c43ff5513> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libvDSP.dylib
0x36368000 - 0x3636bfff  libsystem_network.dylib armv7  <48fe217ed667308bb9413c11f5b5b31d> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_network.dylib
0x3636e000 - 0x36391fff  PrintKit armv7  <279fb51deec3377ab9f820af2da4d915> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PrintKit.framework/PrintKit
0x36396000 - 0x363a5fff  GenerationalStorage armv7  <c581bffc87013530b3c2d017142395e6> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GenerationalStorage.framework/GenerationalStorage
0x3657e000 - 0x3673afff  ImageIO armv7  <df300f66a317352e92354a8a48af3453> /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/ImageIO
0x367d6000 - 0x36b47fff  TextInput armv7  <fbf47e8da82638568e5d2ebd6c47be68> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/TextInput.framework/TextInput
0x36bf6000 - 0x36bfffff  libMobileGestalt.dylib armv7  <bf524f1f6e8237369795867c7e2b4e67> /usr/lib/libMobileGestalt.dylib
0x36d64000 - 0x36d64fff  libkeymgr.dylib armv7  <791bb8b832943b2392c0c35228f52e09> /usr/lib/system/libkeymgr.dylib
0x36d65000 - 0x36e35fff  WebKit armv7  <b79a797a66723db89d6c2f89c0925cf8> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebKit.framework/WebKit
0x36e3c000 - 0x36e42fff  liblaunch.dylib armv7  <8d5c3270e68e3dbbb2a72efd71314bf6> /usr/lib/system/liblaunch.dylib
0x36ee3000 - 0x36ee6fff  CoreTime armv7  <e2f02260f2a63359b9a0a47c69f59c9e> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreTime.framework/CoreTime
0x37084000 - 0x37345fff  libLAPACK.dylib armv7  <5490a87fe5153771b9c67940292842ba> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libLAPACK.dylib
0x37346000 - 0x37383fff  FTServices armv7  <9defdfb8c14239638d3a8efc9c4382de> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FTServices.framework/FTServices
0x37384000 - 0x373bbfff  Security armv7  <195ed72ea7583470958d72652bd84f03> /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Security
0x37487000 - 0x374c4fff  IOKit armv7  <284ee3241c4a3b43b81b9ff514997013> /System/Library/Frameworks/IOKit.framework/Versions/A/IOKit
0x374c9000 - 0x37512fff  CoreMedia armv7  <16e247e3f4a43fc5a72695092cf8ba96> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreMedia.framework/CoreMedia
0x37660000 - 0x3766bfff  GraphicsServices armv7  <08bfaa5766853884a09cd70f5ae37017> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GraphicsServices.framework/GraphicsServices
0x3766c000 - 0x376b5fff  ManagedConfiguration armv7  <80836b34a3ef389d82f0fa55cadccc61> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ManagedConfiguration.framework/ManagedConfiguration
0x376ba000 - 0x37705fff  CoreLocation armv7  <77f81f93c6483079b547b3552b0247d2> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreLocation.framework/CoreLocation
0x37706000 - 0x37707fff  DataMigration armv7  <4179a9f217a8300d93c14b6fd87e5c31> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataMigration.framework/DataMigration
0x3770a000 - 0x377b7fff  libxml2.2.dylib armv7  <78462273eb5b38d1a0873b02f0e35e23> /usr/lib/libxml2.2.dylib
0x378a2000 - 0x378a2fff  Accelerate armv7  <a62771c826753815a5cae96eaa60ffd7> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Accelerate
0x37ccc000 - 0x37cd4fff  MobileWiFi armv7  <f07cb8d6dadf36919bae8ef6e5ce1749> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileWiFi.framework/MobileWiFi
0x37d16000 - 0x37d19fff  libmacho.dylib armv7  <d7f346d1c62d35b18fec919efc67eb84> /usr/lib/system/libmacho.dylib
0x37d1a000 - 0x37d71fff  CoreAudio armv7  <d0d388a7373036a08561809242f5a5f6> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreAudio.framework/CoreAudio
0x37ec4000 - 0x37eddfff  libRIP.A.dylib armv7  <ad22ea5ee99a358691f9820e62c85058> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Resources/libRIP.A.dylib
0x37f99000 - 0x37f99fff  libCVMSPluginSupport.dylib armv7  <85582e1094633fccb52b50ca13c5a5d0> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libCVMSPluginSupport.dylib
0x37f9a000 - 0x37f9afff  libgcc_s.1.dylib armv7  <69d8dab7388b33d38b30708fd6b6a340> /usr/lib/libgcc_s.1.dylib
```

```
(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
    //[dbLogic LogWebData:webData];
    if( xmlParser )
    {
        [xmlParser release];
    }

    xmlParser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData: webData];
    [xmlParser setDelegate: self];
    [xmlParser setShouldResolveExternalEntities: YES];
    [xmlParser parse];
    [act stopAnimating];
    [connection release];
    [webData release];  

    if (orderArray.count==0 && [statusid isEqualToString:@"28"]) {

        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"OrderWork" message:@"No New Work Orders are available" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"OK",nil];
        [alert show];

    }else if(orderArray.count==0 && [statusid isEqualToString:@"6"])
        {

            UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"OrderWork" message:@"No Today's Jobs are available" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"OK",nil];
            [alert show];
    }
    [tableView reloadData];
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem.enabled=YES;
    tableView.userInteractionEnabled=YES;
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setApplicationIconBadgeNumber:0];

    btnNewOrders.userInteractionEnabled=YES;
    btnTodaysJobs.userInteractionEnabled=YES;

}
```

Comment: Hey Viraj have you found your solution yet? Because I am getting same issues! :(

Comment: could you show what you get in the log in xcode? also, when u ran it in xcode, were you able to find out where it crashed?