# iPhone application is working properly on simulator but crashes on iPad

Tags: iphone, ios-simulator, crash-reports

I am running application on iPhone simulator, it's working fine but it crashes when i run it on Device.
    Crash report is not understood by me properly.
    Please can anybody tell me how to handle such crash ?

```
Here is the crash report :

Incident Identifier: 77B0FF91-C78E-4BAD-B6BF-E9F10AEA494C
CrashReporter Key:   a57294fe66cc148133bb27c8bde27a2c507aa3ce
Hardware Model:      iPad2,1
Process:         New2You4Kids [397]
Path:            /var/mobile/Applications/CE2E1DAC-A369-4867-8640-E82788D6AB53/New2You4Kids.app/New2You4Kids
Identifier:      New2You4Kids
Version:         ??? (???)
Code Type:       ARM (Native)
Parent Process:  launchd [1]

Date/Time:       2013-04-01 16:50:22.431 +0530
OS Version:      iOS 6.1.2 (10B146)
Report Version:  104

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0xf0000008
Crashed Thread:  0

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x3a4595b0 0x3a456000 + 13744
1   CoreFoundation                  0x3254630c 0x32543000 + 13068
2   QuartzCore                      0x341c9590 0x341b7000 + 75152
3   QuartzCore                      0x341cc9fc 0x341b7000 + 88572
4   QuartzCore                      0x341cc7ae 0x341b7000 + 87982
5   QuartzCore                      0x341bca70 0x341b7000 + 23152
6   QuartzCore                      0x341bb0a4 0x341b7000 + 16548
7   QuartzCore                      0x341baeac 0x341b7000 + 16044
8   CoreFoundation                  0x325da6ca 0x32543000 + 620234
9   CoreFoundation                  0x325d89bc 0x32543000 + 612796
10  CoreFoundation                  0x3254bede 0x32543000 + 36574
11  CoreFoundation                  0x3254bd44 0x32543000 + 36164
12  GraphicsServices                0x361002e6 0x360fb000 + 21222
13  UIKit                           0x344612fc 0x3440a000 + 357116
14  New2You4Kids                    0x000df786 0xde000 + 6022
15  libdyld.dylib                   0x3a895b1c 0x3a894000 + 6940

Thread 1 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3a94c648 0x3a94b000 + 5704
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x3a87c974 0x3a874000 + 35188
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x3a87c654 0x3a874000 + 34388

Thread 2 name:  WebThread
Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3a94beb4 0x3a94b000 + 3764
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3a94c048 0x3a94b000 + 4168
2   CoreFoundation                  0x325da040 0x32543000 + 618560
3   CoreFoundation                  0x325d8d9e 0x32543000 + 613790
4   CoreFoundation                  0x3254beb8 0x32543000 + 36536
5   CoreFoundation                  0x3254bd44 0x32543000 + 36164
6   WebCore                         0x38512500 0x38508000 + 42240
7   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3a8b530e 0x3a8a4000 + 70414
8   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3a8b51d4 0x3a8a4000 + 70100

Thread 3 name:  com.apple.NSURLConnectionLoader
Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3a94beb4 0x3a94b000 + 3764
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3a94c048 0x3a94b000 + 4168
2   CoreFoundation                  0x325da040 0x32543000 + 618560
3   CoreFoundation                  0x325d8d9e 0x32543000 + 613790
4   CoreFoundation                  0x3254beb8 0x32543000 + 36536
5   CoreFoundation                  0x3254bd44 0x32543000 + 36164
6   Foundation                      0x32e983d0 0x32e6b000 + 185296
7   Foundation                      0x32f1be80 0x32e6b000 + 724608
8   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3a8b530e 0x3a8a4000 + 70414
9   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3a8b51d4 0x3a8a4000 + 70100

Thread 4 name:  com.apple.CFSocket.private
Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3a95c594 0x3a94b000 + 71060
1   CoreFoundation                  0x325de1f2 0x32543000 + 635378
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3a8b530e 0x3a8a4000 + 70414
3   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3a8b51d4 0x3a8a4000 + 70100

Thread 5 name:  com.apple.coremedia.player.async
Thread 5:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3a95c08c 0x3a94b000 + 69772
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3a8add2a 0x3a8a4000 + 40234
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3a8b7f14 0x3a8a4000 + 81684
3   CoreMedia                       0x32b318ac 0x32b2e000 + 14508
4   MediaToolbox                    0x33623e56 0x33620000 + 15958
5   CoreMedia                       0x32b4f890 0x32b2e000 + 137360
6   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3a8b530e 0x3a8a4000 + 70414
7   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3a8b51d4 0x3a8a4000 + 70100

Thread 6 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.root.default-priority
Thread 6:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3a94beb4 0x3a94b000 + 3764
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3a94c048 0x3a94b000 + 4168
2   CoreFoundation                  0x325da040 0x32543000 + 618560
3   CoreFoundation                  0x325d8d9e 0x32543000 + 613790
4   CoreFoundation                  0x3254beb8 0x32543000 + 36536
5   CoreFoundation                  0x3254bd44 0x32543000 + 36164
6   CFNetwork                       0x322ad2ca 0x3225a000 + 340682
7   Foundation                      0x32f401c2 0x32e6b000 + 872898
8   Foundation                      0x32e99642 0x32e6b000 + 190018
9   Foundation                      0x32ed5802 0x32e6b000 + 436226
10  New2You4Kids                    0x000e2d96 0xde000 + 19862
11  libdispatch.dylib               0x3a87611c 0x3a874000 + 8476
12  libdispatch.dylib               0x3a87a95c 0x3a874000 + 26972
13  libdispatch.dylib               0x3a87aabc 0x3a874000 + 27324
14  libsystem_c.dylib               0x3a8aaa0e 0x3a8a4000 + 27150
15  libsystem_c.dylib               0x3a8aa8a0 0x3a8a4000 + 26784

Thread 7:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3a95cd98 0x3a94b000 + 73112
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3a8aacf6 0x3a8a4000 + 27894
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3a8aaa12 0x3a8a4000 + 27154
3   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3a8aa8a0 0x3a8a4000 + 26784

Thread 8:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3a95cd98 0x3a94b000 + 73112
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3a8aacf6 0x3a8a4000 + 27894
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3a8aaa12 0x3a8a4000 + 27154
3   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3a8aa8a0 0x3a8a4000 + 26784

Thread 9:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3a95cd98 0x3a94b000 + 73112
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3a8aacf6 0x3a8a4000 + 27894
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3a8aaa12 0x3a8a4000 + 27154
3   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3a8aa8a0 0x3a8a4000 + 26784

Thread 10:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3a95cd98 0x3a94b000 + 73112
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3a8aacf6 0x3a8a4000 + 27894
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3a8aaa12 0x3a8a4000 + 27154
3   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3a8aa8a0 0x3a8a4000 + 26784

Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State (32-bit):
    r0: 0x1f35a320    r1: 0x38080a5e      r2: 0x0000035a      r3: 0x025e1f90
    r4: 0xf0000000    r5: 0x1f35a324      r6: 0x028a4670      r7: 0x2fd22988
    r8: 0x1f35a320    r9: 0x0e020297     r10: 0x00000000     r11: 0x1e971800
    ip: 0x3aab6718    sp: 0x2fd2294c      lr: 0x32546311      pc: 0x3a4595b0
  cpsr: 0x20000030

Binary Images:
   0xde000 -    0xfffff +New2You4Kids armv7  <0957774457a437c7afb8dff1cbeb1286> /var/mobile/Applications/CE2E1DAC-A369-4867-8640-E82788D6AB53/New2You4Kids.app/New2You4Kids
0x2fe04000 - 0x2fe24fff  dyld armv7  <454baf45f9a831aa88e1ea4447c58d4e> /usr/lib/dyld
0x31726000 - 0x3180cfff  AVFoundation armv7  <320761e836883aeabf3cb5c53edb636d> /System/Library/Frameworks/AVFoundation.framework/AVFoundation
0x3180d000 - 0x3180dfff  Accelerate armv7  <b68ff92e404931f3bcb6361720f77724> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Accelerate
0x3180e000 - 0x3194cfff  vImage armv7  <30522b92940d3dd184c8e46780594048> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vImage.framework/vImage
0x3194d000 - 0x31a30fff  libBLAS.dylib armv7  <d8edada1cea133458ca779e34a3a7f88> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libBLAS.dylib
0x31a31000 - 0x31ce6fff  libLAPACK.dylib armv7  <9e08aead79d13043bab622402a270fba> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libLAPACK.dylib
0x31ce7000 - 0x31d40fff  libvDSP.dylib armv7  <09e2a5e3e9203950890ba57592523132> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libvDSP.dylib
0x31d41000 - 0x31d52fff  libvMisc.dylib armv7  <7b7d4ccc9f2b364cb0da4251e745545d> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libvMisc.dylib
0x31d53000 - 0x31d53fff  vecLib armv7  <a7751c047dcc35ba8885212e1938b93f> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/vecLib
0x31d54000 - 0x31d65fff  Accounts armv7  <ea2de358b6cc3baab27d6ab809c31e39> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accounts.framework/Accounts
0x31d67000 - 0x31dcbfff  AddressBook armv7  <3001f4364f9d3222b2a500a9f6897af8> /System/Library/Frameworks/AddressBook.framework/AddressBook
0x31dcc000 - 0x31e86fff  AddressBookUI armv7  <0017d0a0c2593522acaaa0eee41775e4> /System/Library/Frameworks/AddressBookUI.framework/AddressBookUI
0x31fd1000 - 0x32259fff  AudioToolbox armv7  <bb11489c87e93a3b8c26aa995a2fdec9> /System/Library/Frameworks/AudioToolbox.framework/AudioToolbox
0x3225a000 - 0x3231ffff  CFNetwork armv7  <4771a5e4f9b83bceb252f0f3d166aaca> /System/Library/Frameworks/CFNetwork.framework/CFNetwork
0x32320000 - 0x32376fff  CoreAudio armv7  <5d534dbf76ff30f4a628f25f56c5f26a> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreAudio.framework/CoreAudio
0x3238a000 - 0x32542fff  CoreData armv7  <3930f672c76535a2abb768ee59958fa7> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreData.framework/CoreData
0x32543000 - 0x32675fff  CoreFoundation armv7  <fcb8d4e838543bcb9a52c9f232b8b4eb> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation
0x32676000 - 0x327aefff  CoreGraphics armv7  <81e213f810a034d4ba411f9b505da2a6> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/CoreGraphics
0x327b0000 - 0x327ebfff  libCGFreetype.A.dylib armv7  <a5d20b80ab1532d8831027a66d2d9eb5> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Resources/libCGFreetype.A.dylib
0x329cf000 - 0x329eafff  libRIP.A.dylib armv7  <ec1487f9bdb93597a3f8d434406ad9bf> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Resources/libRIP.A.dylib
0x329eb000 - 0x32aa0fff  CoreImage armv7  <6ae4ae2461313e3f84c6a8102d5b1b0e> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreImage.framework/CoreImage
0x32aa1000 - 0x32af9fff  CoreLocation armv7  <4107e94cdf043d6089e99cbd30631b07> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreLocation.framework/CoreLocation
0x32b2e000 - 0x32b93fff  CoreMedia armv7  <8592bdc268b83b8886acfc1fdab649ed> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreMedia.framework/CoreMedia
0x32b94000 - 0x32c1cfff  CoreMotion armv7  <908cc54aecf5318e9719c4c9d70ef2e8> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreMotion.framework/CoreMotion
0x32c1d000 - 0x32c73fff  CoreTelephony armv7  <c5a2e59bb15d35b8a8e356e129b78b5e> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreTelephony.framework/CoreTelephony
0x32c74000 - 0x32cd6fff  CoreText armv7  <e135debbc8f937299f4986fc3e9459e3> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreText.framework/CoreText
0x32cd7000 - 0x32ce6fff  CoreVideo armv7  <00f18bb26e663da9ae251a6ec36a19ec> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreVideo.framework/CoreVideo
0x32ce7000 - 0x32d9bfff  EventKit armv7  <f354855acc6535c99836e0c1e13df6b1> /System/Library/Frameworks/EventKit.framework/EventKit
0x32e6b000 - 0x3302efff  Foundation armv7  <0179934581d13346aa7583165108b95c> /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Foundation
0x331e9000 - 0x33232fff  IOKit armv7  <a98ba9fefc7333e4a5a9169198848c62> /System/Library/Frameworks/IOKit.framework/Versions/A/IOKit
0x33233000 - 0x3340bfff  ImageIO armv7  <b5ce84bb074d3de4b07b55da9fd8bfd1> /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/ImageIO
0x33485000 - 0x3361ffff  MediaPlayer armv7  <29ae22068ac9333cb93ea33128e76108> /System/Library/Frameworks/MediaPlayer.framework/MediaPlayer
0x33620000 - 0x3389afff  MediaToolbox armv7  <ed439fc5c9a03f8b9fae43af33de8a57> /System/Library/Frameworks/MediaToolbox.framework/MediaToolbox
0x3389b000 - 0x33921fff  MessageUI armv7  <8dbc0a8e6a253c8c8d6301064f23dfea> /System/Library/Frameworks/MessageUI.framework/MessageUI
0x33922000 - 0x3397bfff  MobileCoreServices armv7  <77da8a9e7f813f5baf37eaa4a87fae84> /System/Library/Frameworks/MobileCoreServices.framework/MobileCoreServices
0x33a6a000 - 0x33a71fff  OpenGLES armv7  <f2ede6b206f336de82cc38619692e762> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/OpenGLES
0x33a73000 - 0x33a73fff  libCVMSPluginSupport.dylib armv7  <2506af1c983f3f09ac69aca44f67e863> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libCVMSPluginSupport.dylib
0x33a77000 - 0x33a79fff  libCoreVMClient.dylib armv7  <af6ff28dce6031baaa850ccc79e5699b> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libCoreVMClient.dylib
0x33a7a000 - 0x33a7efff  libGFXShared.dylib armv7  <a6ac1673a088379aa512ba5cac301f5b> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libGFXShared.dylib
0x33a7f000 - 0x33abcfff  libGLImage.dylib armv7  <b8b8f3a1bfd0345e86aa0c2952534949> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libGLImage.dylib
0x341b7000 - 0x342ccfff  QuartzCore armv7  <c086b6e6cd9d341399bcc3675c82f1fe> /System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/QuartzCore
0x342cd000 - 0x3431afff  QuickLook armv7  <954e3a8bdaf337b085b30fd514ea5f3a> /System/Library/Frameworks/QuickLook.framework/QuickLook
0x3431b000 - 0x34349fff  Security armv7  <fbc24f15bd9e37539cdd6e3576bde938> /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Security
0x343c8000 - 0x34407fff  SystemConfiguration armv7  <410d69b356e533d6a1d538cf33059634> /System/Library/Frameworks/SystemConfiguration.framework/SystemConfiguration
0x3440a000 - 0x3495efff  UIKit armv7  <e138ca6a809b399691d933dd3d58d00e> /System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/UIKit
0x3495f000 - 0x3499dfff  VideoToolbox armv7  <d2e8067306d9346ab4a448f10f336894> /System/Library/Frameworks/VideoToolbox.framework/VideoToolbox
0x34bab000 - 0x34bccfff  ACTFramework armv7  <327ca3ba889730549c2e47a3d88ab89a> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ACTFramework.framework/ACTFramework
0x34c26000 - 0x34c32fff  AccountSettings armv7  <8db45acc4d3d3017af10fa5ee82c2306> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AccountSettings.framework/AccountSettings
0x34c79000 - 0x34c7cfff  ActorKit armv7  <5dfc59258ea63006be9c542e5fafbc45> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ActorKit.framework/ActorKit
0x34c7e000 - 0x34c81fff  AggregateDictionary armv7  <a2170ad876f13ef1b944547913d05af2> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AggregateDictionary.framework/AggregateDictionary
0x34d6a000 - 0x34d7dfff  AirTraffic armv7  <752b64045f4d3ea88a946b53b731ce1a> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AirTraffic.framework/AirTraffic
0x350ad000 - 0x350e8fff  AppSupport armv7  <921794b7d82a3558a0eb860979be199c> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AppSupport.framework/AppSupport
0x350e9000 - 0x3510dfff  AppleAccount armv7  <c54536fbc0f235f693060be33d4d4749> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AppleAccount.framework/AppleAccount
0x3511a000 - 0x35127fff  ApplePushService armv7  <8bad4a9300db3d4d8555535f25c32da4> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ApplePushService.framework/ApplePushService
0x3515b000 - 0x35164fff  AssetsLibraryServices armv7  <de7ca29cd47433cd8eca9c04102f5508> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AssetsLibraryServices.framework/AssetsLibraryServices
0x3517e000 - 0x35195fff  BackBoardServices armv7  <585cc62d83c530ee82988de940c1e161> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/BackBoardServices.framework/BackBoardServices
0x3519f000 - 0x351c3fff  Bom armv7  <b5315d733e123a0781683efdc734064b> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Bom.framework/Bom
0x351d6000 - 0x35205fff  BulletinBoard armv7  <9f46015c5d263064901f7725f4bb93e0> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/BulletinBoard.framework/BulletinBoard
0x35243000 - 0x3524afff  CaptiveNetwork armv7  <a4f4b86cc84839f78ff746f013bcee6f> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CaptiveNetwork.framework/CaptiveNetwork
0x3524b000 - 0x35315fff  Celestial armv7  <a688df527b65382da586ebc87f28c061> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Celestial.framework/Celestial
0x35322000 - 0x35326fff  CertUI armv7  <ce979f715cdb3cb5a0f7935f14cc0b35> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CertUI.framework/CertUI
0x353cc000 - 0x353e5fff  ChunkingLibrary armv7  <ec2f76b3ac723a39bbf3f122d7fe73cf> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ChunkingLibrary.framework/ChunkingLibrary
0x353f9000 - 0x353fefff  CommonUtilities armv7  <f8fea9ee6ca236b0a7fa6c00eb8a0d24> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CommonUtilities.framework/CommonUtilities
0x35483000 - 0x354b3fff  ContentIndex armv7  <00ed488e47ee34ca9f01f2cc911f453c> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ContentIndex.framework/ContentIndex
0x3552f000 - 0x35617fff  CoreMediaStream armv7  <828bf27fe7a3337cbff7dd8837508819> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreMediaStream.framework/CoreMediaStream
0x356c4000 - 0x356c5fff  CoreSurface armv7  <6065f7e040e93d6ea2837e929592cc30> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreSurface.framework/CoreSurface
0x3572d000 - 0x35731fff  CoreTime armv7  <5f0b123555f03d8aa76cc54314907942> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreTime.framework/CoreTime
0x35732000 - 0x35737fff  CrashReporterSupport armv7  <03ee46e3ca3f3920a7174e62096723fb> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CrashReporterSupport.framework/CrashReporterSupport
0x35738000 - 0x35774fff  DataAccess armv7  <d7185042adf63908ae87fe4a5c3f8a6c> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataAccess.framework/DataAccess
0x35909000 - 0x3591bfff  DataAccessExpress armv7  <b9423867a9ef303b87d2e1eac1712957> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataAccessExpress.framework/DataAccessExpress
0x3595a000 - 0x3595bfff  DataMigration armv7  <5903e08348b83f119022cbbf83ad100a> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataMigration.framework/DataMigration
0x3595e000 - 0x35977fff  DictionaryServices armv7  <84669055e3e63d6ab56b8fe7b0476aaa> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DictionaryServices.framework/DictionaryServices
0x3597f000 - 0x35997fff  EAP8021X armv7  <82a73adcf1db3d2f9e57cd22f71e44c9> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/EAP8021X.framework/EAP8021X
0x359a7000 - 0x359abfff  FTClientServices armv7  <6354e5b30919340db3b976312b284fce> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FTClientServices.framework/FTClientServices
0x359ac000 - 0x359e9fff  FTServices armv7  <89c066d12a6031038a9b8c61221abc0a> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FTServices.framework/FTServices
0x359ea000 - 0x35dfdfff  FaceCoreLight armv7  <43de0b31da3b39e4acf85ec2c8d5c65c> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FaceCoreLight.framework/FaceCoreLight
0x35ff5000 - 0x36001fff  GenerationalStorage armv7  <d77ad2367fff37d485480aa39df7d325> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GenerationalStorage.framework/GenerationalStorage
0x36002000 - 0x360fafff  GeoServices armv7  <206a365f6bfe3278a9aecc1601015c7d> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GeoServices.framework/GeoServices
0x360fb000 - 0x36106fff  GraphicsServices armv7  <d4b7fd6509753bff9525fef374ddc359> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GraphicsServices.framework/GraphicsServices
0x36175000 - 0x361f0fff  HomeSharing armv7  <280b77b71df23f1cb5c9a2b76fc53212> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/HomeSharing.framework/HomeSharing
0x361f1000 - 0x361fbfff  IAP armv7  <a9554a91bbb9308f96fcd9fddf596275> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IAP.framework/IAP
0x362b3000 - 0x3632bfff  IMCore armv7  <d5f1d98ec53d3acbb51b116e93923d9c> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IMCore.framework/IMCore
0x363f2000 - 0x3643efff  IMFoundation armv7  <797535fc363c3f818bcd1424251393bf> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IMFoundation.framework/IMFoundation
0x36445000 - 0x36446fff  IOAccelerator armv7  <9655464326203d258d3d0fc7e94651e2> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IOAccelerator.framework/IOAccelerator
0x36447000 - 0x3644cfff  IOMobileFramebuffer armv7  <f38c374982a931d5a47458dd3c34ac59> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IOMobileFramebuffer.framework/IOMobileFramebuffer
0x3644d000 - 0x36451fff  IOSurface armv7  <a55bf03c35de3fd9b56dce82083c3d10> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IOSurface.framework/IOSurface
0x36452000 - 0x36495fff  ImageCapture armv7  <60569acc856831c4bc78c3e7cb0c30cf> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ImageCapture.framework/ImageCapture
0x3649b000 - 0x36641fff  JavaScriptCore armv7  <a5780997f4b738659172f40877c9a7d9> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/JavaScriptCore.framework/JavaScriptCore
0x36672000 - 0x366a8fff  MIME armv7  <c88b555e957e3489b3733a9ede6c7ade> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MIME.framework/MIME
0x366a9000 - 0x366dffff  MMCS armv7  <7f329f193ef138c2b372e8b16e855bce> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MMCS.framework/MMCS
0x366e7000 - 0x366f1fff  MailServices armv7  <a688a9972cb43169a19d2f2f57121a1e> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MailServices.framework/MailServices
0x3670d000 - 0x36765fff  ManagedConfiguration armv7  <44bbb2ba85c8320bb9e73c654b90f8c0> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ManagedConfiguration.framework/ManagedConfiguration
0x36766000 - 0x3676bfff  Marco armv7  <da45fc9b228b3d1fad95e03071441585> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Marco.framework/Marco
0x3677c000 - 0x367f2fff  MediaControlSender armv7  <9fb205b64b5333a495ac61c149e0304b> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MediaControlSender.framework/MediaControlSender
0x367f3000 - 0x367fcfff  MediaRemote armv7  <73da55e989e73cb9ad6e9fdd4604ecc3> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MediaRemote.framework/MediaRemote
0x367fd000 - 0x36811fff  MediaStream armv7  <86443ae270083a829e1797d24cd0d17c> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MediaStream.framework/MediaStream
0x3686f000 - 0x36928fff  Message armv7  <7df6983ae878398f9aee4e5e675ae68b> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Message.framework/Message
0x36931000 - 0x36933fff  MessageSupport armv7  <b838e70face13124a74ea5293cb0d585> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MessageSupport.framework/MessageSupport
0x3693c000 - 0x36969fff  MobileAsset armv7  <3a9e6258ae1230f5b12f1638b09cb974> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileAsset.framework/MobileAsset
0x36996000 - 0x369a5fff  MobileDeviceLink armv7  <817380030c613284a12074d960087522> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileDeviceLink.framework/MobileDeviceLink
0x369ae000 - 0x369b1fff  MobileInstallation armv7  <c63e4b1ae40635cd9c6a7de851c80d10> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileInstallation.framework/MobileInstallation
0x369b2000 - 0x369b8fff  MobileKeyBag armv7  <35882c57076334aeb0641969a9b69ff3> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileKeyBag.framework/MobileKeyBag
0x369f1000 - 0x36a14fff  MobileSync armv7  <1edd78024ae13e9997972ee905bc944e> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileSync.framework/MobileSync
0x36a15000 - 0x36a18fff  MobileSystemServices armv7  <10b4eee2739c353183ac2cfe4e39a443> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileSystemServices.framework/MobileSystemServices
0x36a30000 - 0x36a39fff  MobileWiFi armv7  <bb4efbe3c7273c0fb534f12789756089> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileWiFi.framework/MobileWiFi
0x36a53000 - 0x36b97fff  MusicLibrary armv7  <3870f4cb0c8b36778ad1a3f7556547f7> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MusicLibrary.framework/MusicLibrary
0x36baf000 - 0x36bc8fff  Notes armv7  <3d4a8d4b012a3743b0ffc8dc33fb79e9> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Notes.framework/Notes
0x36bc9000 - 0x36bcbfff  OAuth armv7  <575df12a2f2436af92e31494c3b74465> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/OAuth.framework/OAuth
0x37305000 - 0x3732afff  OpenCL armv7  <5bf059a9deb632678d70099f14f51b82> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/OpenCL.framework/OpenCL
0x3768b000 - 0x376a8fff  PersistentConnection armv7  <c773b3dc885832f8a916de67f24f9f92> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PersistentConnection.framework/PersistentConnection
0x376b2000 - 0x37819fff  PhotoLibrary armv7  <8ebe772b121539d582f4aefc9476ff68> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PhotoLibrary.framework/PhotoLibrary
0x3781a000 - 0x37901fff  PhotoLibraryServices armv7  <e67930f821d53e0992f377b697551039> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PhotoLibraryServices.framework/PhotoLibraryServices
0x3793e000 - 0x37966fff  PrintKit armv7  <3f0b9c58a458358eb506858e8ff9e1fe> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PrintKit.framework/PrintKit
0x37967000 - 0x379dbfff  ProofReader armv7  <9cb25467554637bcb268ba30527d3c0f> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ProofReader.framework/ProofReader
0x379dc000 - 0x379e4fff  ProtocolBuffer armv7  <d1f2888d5e5a39cca6a6179a35c86770> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ProtocolBuffer.framework/ProtocolBuffer
0x37b20000 - 0x37b31fff  SpringBoardServices armv7  <e2571f80a0ad3dc580c69794457bd887> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SpringBoardServices.framework/SpringBoardServices
0x37b32000 - 0x37b46fff  SpringBoardUI armv7  <896351fe7cd630bd8c8670e97e133f4c> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SpringBoardUI.framework/SpringBoardUI
0x37b72000 - 0x37c4dfff  StoreServices armv7  <6d45f42eff2736d18cdd81af0473dd5a> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/StoreServices.framework/StoreServices
0x37c9b000 - 0x37c9dfff  TCC armv7  <d5bef30a5bda315194173b862975f9fb> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/TCC.framework/TCC
0x37c9e000 - 0x37cbbfff  TelephonyUI armv7  <f4944c45b790382ea44b08f088b27d6f> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/TelephonyUI.framework/TelephonyUI
0x37cbc000 - 0x37cc9fff  TelephonyUtilities armv7  <803d7a92439238ee942086999c481eb6> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/TelephonyUtilities.framework/TelephonyUtilities
0x37cca000 - 0x380eefff  TextInput armv7  <d54d5ca42b503f26ab45e5efd4b87135> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/TextInput.framework/TextInput
0x380ef000 - 0x3811dfff  ToneLibrary armv7  <99c310617b7d3fe4bdabf13892fc6f0c> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ToneLibrary.framework/ToneLibrary
0x3814c000 - 0x381ecfff  UIFoundation armv7  <9a464526e26634bc834537e5ac3abf1f> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIFoundation.framework/UIFoundation
0x384e8000 - 0x38507fff  WebBookmarks armv7  <77b65bc9c87b367ebea9a5b7984b13a5> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebBookmarks.framework/WebBookmarks
0x38508000 - 0x38e37fff  WebCore armv7  <ce52fd40ccc236c4b86c020beabb1bb0> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebCore.framework/WebCore
0x38e38000 - 0x38f15fff  WebKit armv7  <dee20c7689bc3e029172b488d8c5f772> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebKit.framework/WebKit
0x38fb9000 - 0x38fbffff  XPCKit armv7  <cf94468d5a44389e8fdfd2b0802c4378> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/XPCKit.framework/XPCKit
0x38fc0000 - 0x38fc7fff  XPCObjects armv7  <723fe314ab95381cbfa69a0000005692> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/XPCObjects.framework/XPCObjects
0x3911a000 - 0x39155fff  iCalendar armv7  <1c4486846efd3c9480174d9e7df8cec6> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/iCalendar.framework/iCalendar
0x39437000 - 0x3946ffff  iTunesStore armv7  <e88e4626134b32f8bac8e3f79afddf24> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/iTunesStore.framework/iTunesStore
0x39cd7000 - 0x39cddfff  libAccessibility.dylib armv7  <f40705b5e9c43ce3b1f185fe690b9ac8> /usr/lib/libAccessibility.dylib
0x39cde000 - 0x39cf4fff  libCRFSuite.dylib armv7  <5a8a3d18a1ff3c97bd773705fef2d81c> /usr/lib/libCRFSuite.dylib
0x39d0a000 - 0x39d0bfff  libMobileCheckpoint.dylib armv7  <1e9d719e2f4e3b41970b635e47ee8058> /usr/lib/libMobileCheckpoint.dylib
0x39d0c000 - 0x39d18fff  libMobileGestalt.dylib armv7  <ea41737238273d73b173ec09358d7b62> /usr/lib/libMobileGestalt.dylib
0x39d2a000 - 0x39d2afff  libSystem.B.dylib armv7  <7aeeab280f7e361e9986d962d0fa5281> /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
0x39e26000 - 0x39e47fff  libarchive.2.dylib armv7  <b63f679c9ee03372b1e5f881febeaff6> /usr/lib/libarchive.2.dylib
0x39e48000 - 0x39e54fff  libbsm.0.dylib armv7  <3870b1c8b1783b788bd51da1a04eae6e> /usr/lib/libbsm.0.dylib
0x39e55000 - 0x39e5efff  libbz2.1.0.dylib armv7  <b04d27fa0f2d31d8bd0745f8aa0d7f67> /usr/lib/libbz2.1.0.dylib
0x39e5f000 - 0x39ea9fff  libc++.1.dylib armv7  <ceb9fb64fb203d3a94063a9db6590ca4> /usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib
0x39eaa000 - 0x39ebdfff  libc++abi.dylib armv7  <4b8520bc534231ae97ce146e076bc7bf> /usr/lib/libc++abi.dylib
0x39eee000 - 0x39fdbfff  libiconv.2.dylib armv7  <ac23bb84e91e35418c9a2fb4792658b2> /usr/lib/libiconv.2.dylib
0x39fdc000 - 0x3a125fff  libicucore.A.dylib armv7  <da9d04cc6f6d3825aa52636342ef1e04> /usr/lib/libicucore.A.dylib
0x3a12d000 - 0x3a12dfff  liblangid.dylib armv7  <a10d8f96815d35e0a1d2c7b998a941f3> /usr/lib/liblangid.dylib
0x3a130000 - 0x3a137fff  liblockdown.dylib armv7  <996afbc31d8b3f2a907be2427509a4c8> /usr/lib/liblockdown.dylib
0x3a274000 - 0x3a417fff  libmecabra.dylib armv7  <0747e596e9983bd6a76cf8349da325e4> /usr/lib/libmecabra.dylib
0x3a418000 - 0x3a42dfff  libmis.dylib armv7  <7502589f14733beb963c542fa40438c8> /usr/lib/libmis.dylib
0x3a456000 - 0x3a554fff  libobjc.A.dylib armv7  <79e5d714945834e4b2587abfc6c7269c>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7976805/application-not-running-in-ios-5    Can you add some code ?

Comment: Check the Xib are linked properly..

Comment: You need to symbolicate this crash log. Drag it into the organiser in Xcode, on the same machine that was used to build the app.

Comment: try debugging using exception breakpoints. Check out the link http://pinkstone.co.uk/what-is-an-exception-breakpoint/

Comment: did you add tjat lib files from frameworks

Comment: @ganeshmanoj : I have added frameworks to it. Need to add any lib ?

Comment: i am asking have you added libz.1.2.5.dylib?

Comment: @ganeshmanoj : I have not added it. Just added now will check and inform.

Comment: @Pushkraj...ok after adding me tell me

Comment: @ganeshmanoj : It's not working though I added libz.1.2.5.dylib to xcode hierarchy.

Please help me out.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27775/discussion-between-pushkraj-and-ganesh-manoj)

Comment: @ganeshmanoj : Done it Bro :-) Managed all releases. And on one screen there was two times release for 1 button. So it was crashing. Feeling relax.

Comment: nice better to use arc inorder to avoid memory issues