# General GPU programming on iPhone

Tags: ios, iphone, gpgpu

Is the GPU available as a resource for general application programming for the iPhone? I want to know if I can utilize the iPhone's GPU for GPGPU, preferably by the OpenCL API.

Comment: See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3259121/1144632

Comment: Thanks, for the link but those answers are from 2011. Do they still apply?

Comment: Yes. OpenCL is still only available on Mac OS. See https://developer.apple.com/opencl/